# Setting attributes of html element inline

Tags: javascript, html

Here, I'm trying to define a HTML attribute called `zerg`, and display it when a paragraph is clicked, but instead, it displays "undefined" when it is clicked. What's wrong with [the code that I've written](http://jsfiddle.net/QrrpB/1339/), and what is the correct way to do this?

```
<p onclick = "alert(this.zerg);" zerg = "Why doesn't this work?">Click here!</p>
```

Comment: Attributes are not the same as properties. `this.getAttribute("zerg");` though it's not a valid attribute. You can use `data-zerg` to at least be HTML5 compliant.

Comment: As a little background read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: "Unobtrusive JavaScript" is a religion.

Comment: I seem to be very religious. :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to be HTML5-compliant, the attribute should be named `data-zerg` instead of `zerg`. Try this:

```
<p onclick = "alert(this.getAttribute('data-zerg'));" data-zerg = "Now it works as intended!">Click here!</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QrrpB/1340/

Comment: Regarding your answer... did you know any of this before you asked the question?

Comment: @squint No, I asked the question because I hadn't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
<p onclick = "alert(this.getAttribute('zerg' ));" zerg = "Why doesn't this work?">Click here!</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use the `getAttribute()` method:

```html
<p onclick = "alert(this.getAttribute('zerg'));" zerg = "Why doesn't this work?">Click here!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :-

```
   <p onclick = "javascript:alert(this.getAttribute('zerg'));" zerg="Now it works as 
intended!">Click here!</p>
```

`this` refer to current element. So , you can use `this.getAttribute()` as inline code.